# Edit a word paragraph using C#.net

Tags: .net, ms-word, interop, range, paragraphs

am working on a word document Programmatically using C#.net, Interop.Word, I have paragraphs in this document starting and ending with a "#".

Example:

Once upon a time, there was a #little girl who lived in a village near the forest.  Whenever she went out, the little girl wore a red riding cloak, so everyone in the village called her Little Red Riding Hood.#

One morning, Little Red Riding Hood #asked her mother if she could go to visit her grandmother as it had been awhile since they'd seen each other.#

"That's a good idea," her mother said.  #So they packed a nice basket for Little Red Riding Hood to take to her grandmother.#

Now between all # I need the text be bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that.

```
        oWord.Selection.HomeKey( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdStory );
        oWord.Selection.ClearFormatting();

        bool done = false;
        while ( !done )
        {
           object txt = "#*#";
           object oFalse = false;
           object oTrue = true;
           object wdWrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
           oWord.Selection.Find.Execute( ref txt, ref oFalse, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref wdWrap, ref oFalse );
           if ( oWord.Selection.Find.Found == false )
           {
              done = true;
           }
           else
           {
              oWord.Selection.Font.Bold = 1;
              oWord.Selection.Text = oWord.Selection.Text.Substring( 1, oWord.Selection.Text.Length - 2 );
              oWord.Selection.MoveRight( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter );
           }
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want to remove the "#" then just remove the line:  oWord.Selection.Text = oWord.Selection.Text.Substring( 1, oWord.Selection.Text.Length - 2 );

Comment: Thanks dear, it worked fine, still have one prob, last 2 ranges there is no break line between them such as: #"That's a good idea," her mother said#. #So they packed a nice basket for Little Red Riding Hood to take to her grandmother.#   The code couldn't find the last range!

Comment: Fixed that and updated the code.  The change was to the line:                    oWord.Selection.MoveRight( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter );

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Dim done As Boolean
    done = False
While Not done
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "#*#"
        .Replacement.Text = "*"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

 Selection.Find.Execute

 If Selection.Find.Found = False Then
    done = True
 Else
    Selection.Text = Mid(Selection.Text, 2, Len(Selection.Text) - 2)
    Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
End If

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you plz clarify to my why you are using the * between the 2 # in Find.Text?  Moreover I want that the whole words between the 2 # be in bold, means each 2 # make a range to be bold

Comment: Dear Derek, that saved my life except that I have few ques: First am using C#.net so I did some changes to your code such as I don't have replacement.Text in C#.net so I left it empty, Now your code select just the first range between the 2 # the other ranges are not edited

Comment: Can you post your c# code now?  It is fine to ignore the Replacement.Text  Do you still have the "while" loop?  And did you want the # symbols to be deleted? (and just leave the words between the #?)

Comment: Dear, I posted my code as an answer, thx a gain for your help, so this is working well,except that it is working on one range, I need it to work on all ranges between 2 #

Answer (score 0):

```
oWord.Selection.ClearFormatting();

 bool done = false;
 while (!done)
 {
    object txt = "#*#";
    object oFalse = false;
     object oTrue = true;
    object wdWrap =      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
 oWord.Selection.Find.Execute(ref txt, ref oFalse, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref oFalse, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref wdWrap  , ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
  if (oWord.Selection.Find.Found == false)
     {
        done = true;
     }
  oWord.Selection.Text = oWord.Selection.Text.Substring(2 - 1, oWord.Selection.Text.Length - 2);
   oWord.Selection.Font.BoldBi = 1;
   oWord.Selection.Bookmarks.Add("TM2011_517_1", ref oMissing);
}
```